# Preventing resetting of form after js rejected validation

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a survey that on button submit the first thing it runs in my js is validation if required fields are entered. Basically:

```
if (x == null) {
    alert("You forgot to enter a required field!.");
    return false;
};
```

Is there any way from preventing the page from refreshing/resetting what has previously been filled out if they forgot one required field?

This survey stores to local storage if that matters or can be used to help here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquerys `.submit` function (if using Jquery):

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){
    if (x == null) {
        alert("You forgot to enter a required field!.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these answer first:

- [How to validate with Javascript an Input text with Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563028/how-to-validate-with-javascript-an-input-text-with-hours-and-minutes)
- [Form Validation using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165691/form-validation-using-javascript)
- [Validate email address textbox using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635533/validate-email-address-textbox-using-javascript)

if you're not interested in using a framework like `jQuery` this is how it could be done:

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validate()">

function validate() {
    var input_value = document.forms["form"][" .. input name .. "].value;
    if( input_value == '' ) return false;
}
```

If you have multiple inputs, I would suggest looping through them with a `foreach` loop.

With `jQuery` it would be something like:

```
$( '#formID' ).on( 'submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    // check input value
    if( valid input ) $( this ).submit();
});
```

Interesting read: [return false vs preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

Handle on submit event during form submission and return false in handler method.

Comment: how does this add to the previous two answers?

Comment: Previous answers weren't yet submitted, when I took to answer this.