# i am getting error message but not clearing the fields after entering in the text box

Tags: javascript, html

the below is the script i have written, by using below code i am getting error message properly but, if i enter the field the error message still be displaying any idea how to clear the error message.

```
var flag=0
     function otpValidate()
     (
         otp=oneTimePass.onetimepass.value
         if(otp=="")
         (
             document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML="Enter one time password"
             flag=1;
         )else if(otp.length != 6)
         (
             document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML="PIN must be 6 digits"
             flag=1
         )
     )   
     function check(form)
 (
     flag==0
     otpValidate()
     if(flag=1)
         return false

     else
         return true
 )
```

Comment: what line is erroring out?  is oneTimePass an object with an attribute of .onetimepass that is not null?  Obviously that would cause an error if so

Comment: replace  `function otpValidate() (... )` to `function otpValidate() {... }`

Comment: learn the difference in { vs (  - it seems to be popping up everywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form Validation using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165691/form-validation-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You have many errors.

`if(flag=1)` is not a condition but an allocation. Write `if(flag==1)` instead.

Replace `function otpValidate() (... )` to `function otpValidate() {... }`.

It's the same for if statement. Replace `if() (...)` by `if() {...}`

**Note :** At the end line you should add `;` in javascript

---

*Code without mistake :*

```js
var flag = 0;
function otpValidate() {
     otp = oneTimePass.onetimepass.value;
     if(otp == "") {
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "Enter one time password";
         flag = 1;
     } else if(otp.length != 6) { 
         document.getElementById('error0').innerHTML = "PIN must be 6 digits";
         flag = 1;
     }
 }  
 function check(form) {
     flag = 0;
     otpValidate();
     if (flag == 1)
         return false;
     else
         return true;
 }
```

Comment: i did that because i was not able to post i jus tried putting single equal sign n i am able to post it . that was not error in my code ...

Comment: just remove my name, and rewrite his code without mistake

Comment: JavaScript actually doesn't require a ; at the end of lines: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: bcoz stack over flow was not allowing me to post this code so i removed the braces and i have added brackets. the code above is my proper code but m not able to clear the error message after entering the field. help me out its urgent.